# MAUI error: Don't know about Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color

Tags: android, xamarin, colors, maui

I'm new on MAUI, so please be patient.
I get this error: **"System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color'"** when I try to start debugging the application on a Samsung (android).
When I run it with an emulator (Pixel 5 - API 31, Android 12.0) I don't have any error.

As you can see in the attached code, I tried to return the object of type **Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Color.FromRgb(0, 180, 0).ToHex());** hoping that the error will disappear.
Instead, the following error appeared: **System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about Android.Maui.Graphics.Color**

Please, what could I do to get rid of the error and be able to test the application on the Samsung phone as well?
Thank You

In the application I use Color objects like:

```
public class Aditiv
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Cod { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        //public Color BackgroundRow { get; set; }
        public Color Culoare
        {
            get
            {
                switch (CategoryId)
                {
                    //case 1:
                    //    return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Color.FromRgb(0, 180, 0).ToHex());
                    //    //return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#00FF00");
                    //case 2:
                    //    return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Color.FromRgb(255, 200, 0).ToHex());
                    //    //return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FFAA00");
                    //case 3:
                    //    return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Color.FromRgb(200, 0, 0).ToHex());
                    //    //return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FF0000");
                    //default:
                    //    return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0).ToHex());
                    //    //return Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000");

                    case 1:
                        return Color.FromRgb(0, 180, 0);
                    case 2:
                        return Color.FromRgb(255, 200, 0);
                    case 3:
                        return Color.FromRgb(200, 0, 0);
                    default:
                        return Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't use an Android specific class in shared code.  And I wouldn't name your class `Color` there are several `Color` classes already

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can not use Android specific class in shared code just as Jason said.

For how to use class Color in maui, you can check document [Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/colors?view=net-maui-7.0).

In maui,you can use the following static methods to create Color objects:

- `Color.FromRgb` from float RGB values that range from 0 to 1.
- `Color.FromRgb` from double RGB values that range from 0 to 1.
- `Color.FromRgb` from byte RGB values that range from 0 to 255.
- `Color.FromInt` from int RGB values that range from 0 to 255.
- `Color.FromRgba` from float RGBA values that range from 0 to 1.
- `Color.FromRgba` from double RGBA values that range from 0 to 1.
- `Color.FromRgba` from byte RGBA values that range from 0 to 255.
- `Color.FromRgba` from int RGBA values that range from 0 to 255.
- `Color.FromRgba` from a string-based hexadecimal value in the form
  "#RRGGBBAA" or "#RRGGBB" or "#RGBA" or "#RGB", where each letter
  corresponds to a hexadecimal digit for the alpha, red, green, and
  blue channels.
- `Color.FromHsla` from float HSLA values.
- `Color.FromHsla` from double HSLA values.
- `Color.FromHsv` from float HSV values that range from 0 to 1.
- `Color.FromHsv` from int HSV values that range from 0 to 255.
- Color.FromHsva from float HSVA values.
- `Color.FromHsva` from int HSV values.
- `Color.FromInt` from an int value calculated as (B + 256 * (G + 256 *
  (R + 256 * A))).
- `Color.FromUint` from a uint value calculated as (B + 256 * (G + 256 *
  (R + 256 * A))).
- `Color.FromArgb` from a string-based hexadecimal value in the form
  "#AARRGGBB" or "#RRGGBB" or "#ARGB" or "RGB", where each letter
  corresponds to a hexadecimal digit for the alpha, red, green, and
  blue channels.